# Wipe H2 data without dropping table

Tags: java, spring, junit, h2

I am writing JUnit test for one of my project and the tests are all done with H2 database.

The set up consist of XML files (contains spring beans and db setup), SQL files (contain data/schema) and java files (just tests)

Whenever the JUnit test suite is run some test will fail due to duplicate data (because H2 is in memory) and I was wondering if there are a way to wipe the H2 data before certain class?

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_CLASS)
```

Already tried and it is not usable in our case due to time constraint that was needed to run some of our tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("test.xml")
public class ABCTest {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ABC.class);

    @Autowired
    private ABCDao;

    ....

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
       ABCDao = null;
       ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    ...

    }

}
```

Above is pretty much the set up for each class or similarly constructed.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    ABCTest.class,
    DEFTest.class,
    GHITest.class,
    ....
    TUVTest.class, //this fails <---
    XYXTest.class

})

public class AllTests {
}
```

If the test was run individually it doesn't have problem just the suite would fail due to the data in the memory.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

This code will effectively wipe your whole H2 DB (just run it before any test method using `@Before`, JUnit Rule, whatever):

```
public static void truncateAll(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws SQLException {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE");

    try {
        Iterator var1 = getTableNames(jdbcTemplate).iterator();

        while(var1.hasNext()) {
            String tableName = (String)var1.next();
            jdbcTemplate.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName);
        }
    } finally {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE");
    }

}

private static List<String> getTableNames(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws SQLException {
    return (List)jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback() {
        public List<String> doInConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = metaData.getTables((String)null, (String)null, "%", new String[]{"TABLE"});
            ArrayList tableNames = Lists.newArrayList();

            try {
                while(tables.next()) {
                    tableNames.add(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
                }
            } finally {
                tables.close();
            }

            return tableNames;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this utility class to isolate tets in your class like this:

```
TestIsolator.clearDatabase(jdbcTemplate);
```

Utility class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

/**
 * Вспомогательные методы для обеспечения изоляции тестов.
 */
@UtilityClass
public class TestIsolator {

    /**
     * Очистить базу от возможных рудиментов ранее выполненных тестов. Очищает все таблицы базы.
     */
    public void clearDatabase(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        clearDatabase(jdbcTemplate, getTableNames(jdbcTemplate));
    }

    /**
     * Очистить указанные таблицы от возможных рудиментов ранее выполненных тестов.
     */
    public void clearDatabase(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, List<String> tableNames) {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE");
        tableNames.forEach(tableName -> {
            jdbcTemplate.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName + " RESTART IDENTITY");
            jdbcTemplate.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE " + tableName + "_ID_SEQ" + " RESTART WITH 1");
        });
        jdbcTemplate.execute("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE");
    }

    /**
     * Получить список таблиц базы.
     */
    private List<String> getTableNames(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {

        Object tableNames = jdbcTemplate.execute((ConnectionCallback<Object>) callback -> {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

            try (ResultSet tables = callback.getMetaData().getTables(
                null, null, "%", new String[]{"TABLE"})) {
                while (tables.next()) {
                    names.add(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
                }
            }

            return names;
        });

        return (List<String>) tableNames;
    }
}
```